# Variant column not storing elements with NaN value

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am loading two parquet files both have 1 row each into a variant column in a table on Snowflake.
When i read those two files and print fields using python , i see same number of fields (30 in this case). 
When i load those two parquet files into a variant data type column into a table on a snowflake and query that table, i see only 29 fields from one file and 30 fields from other file.

when i look at the python output for this missing field, i see the one file has a value (13 in this case)  and other file has a value as NaN.

For some reason, Snowflake is not showing the field that has a empty value.

Do i need to do something different while loading into snowflake to not ignore fields that doesn't have value in the parquet files.

Comment: Could you share an example record of the variant column and the query that you are using to query it?

Answer (score 3):

Parquet file load into Snowflake does omit `null` fields (or `NaN`, treated equally within the Parquet file) and [offers no options](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#type-parquet) to project them with `null` values in the `VARIANT` representation. This is an expected behaviour for semi-structured file-loads currently.

However, the [semi-structured data querying](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-semistructured.html) behaviour permits looking up non-existent field names across rows, with a `NULL` returned when the field is not found in any row.

Here's an example where two rows are missing a field due to [`NaN`s](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-numeric.html#float-float4-float8) being treated as `null`s within the source Parquet file:

```sql
> SELECT V FROM PRQ;

+-------------------------------+                                               
| V                             |
|-------------------------------|
| {                             |
|   "a": 1.00,                  |
|   "b": "foo"                  |
| }                             |
| {                             |
|   "a": 2.00,                  |
|   "b": "bar"                  |
| }                             |
| {                             |
|   "a": 3.00,                  |
|   "b": "spam"                 |
| }                             |
| {                             |
|   "b": "eggs"  [a is missing] |
| }                             |
| {                             |
|   "b": "ham"   [a is missing] |
| }                             |
+-------------------------------+
```

Since querying `V:a` will emit nulls on the final two rows, you can leverage [`IFNULL`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/ifnull.html) to re-add the `NaN`s (if the data cannot truly be `null`):

```sql
> SELECT V:b, IFNULL(V:a, 'NaN') FROM PRQ;

+--------+--------------------+                                                  
| V:B    | IFNULL(V:A, 'NAN') |
|--------+--------------------|
| "foo"  | 1                  |
| "bar"  | 2                  |
| "spam" | 3                  |
| "eggs" | NaN                |
| "ham"  | NaN                |
+--------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you fro the clarification.. I was able to get the values NULL if i query using variant column: element ... is there is a easy way to basically take all distinct elements from the variant column and flatten that into separate columns like col1, col2, col3... so i have fixed schema all the time and elements that doesn't have a value on a give file will display NULL value on that particular row...